# embed fonts into eps figure with ghostscript

Tags: eps, ghostscript

I have a figure (EPS format), that I include in a large tex file. I would like to embed the fonts into the eps figure before including it. How can I do this with ghostcript on windows?

Comment: it's not an answer (sorry i don't know how to do that...) but it might be a (nasty) workarround: safe as as .pdf_tex via inkscape: http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/LaTeX

Comment: Does https://www.karlrupp.net/2016/01/embed-all-fonts-in-pdfs-latex-pdflatex/ help?